# loading multiple json into R

Tags: r, json

I'm trying to load multiple JSON files into R. These JSON files are the output of extracting data from PDF using Adobe Document Services. the structure is the same.

[image]

I load the jsons:

```
json_files <- list.files(path = unzip_temp, pattern = "*.json", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
```

and I'm using the jsonlite to read the files:

```
json_data <- ldply(.data = json_files, .fun = fromJSON, flatten = TRUE)
```

but I get an error:

> Error in list_to_dataframe(res, attr(.data, "split_labels"), .id,
> id_as_factor) :  Results must be all atomic, or all data frames

how do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Without a sample it's hard to tell, but since it's having trouble with converting to data.frame, I would try disabling that as an argument for `fromJSON`.

`json_data <- ldply(.data = json_files, .fun = fromJSON, flatten = TRUE, simplifyDataFrame = FALSE)`

If that still errors, try `simplifyVector = FALSE` as well. If that fails, post more information :)

Comment: Thanks Marcus. I tried both and it failed, I have added more information.

Comment: You're parsed json has be to able to be combined into a data.frame. Given the structure of the file, in particular the inconsistent number of elements, it won't be able to auto-combine the files. You need either a custom function for the `.fun` argument or try using `lapply`/`llply`